# ReactiveUI and observing nested properties

Tags: c#, xaml, reactiveui

My problem is that my subscription to a nested property isn't responding.

Here's my XAML:

```
<TextBox Header="Enter test data:" 
         Text="{Binding UserEntryTest.Synced.Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The property in the view model (extract):

```
private EditableFieldSynced<string> userEntryTest;
public EditableFieldSynced<string> UserEntryTest
{
    get { return userEntryTest; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref userEntryTest, value); }
}
```

The property `Synced` in `EditableFieldSynced<T>` is actually in a base class that inherits `ReactiveObject`:

```
public T _synced;
public T Synced
{
    get { return _synced; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _synced, value); }
}
```

And in its contructor I subscribe to `Synced` like this:

this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Synced.Value)
       .Subscribe(x => this.ApplyLocalChanges(x));

Actually, whichever class I put in this subscription, it doesn't respond when the user inputs text...

I'm new to ReactiveUI, what am I doing wrong?

Of course, if I flatten the model with a property `ValueSynced` in `EditableFieldSynced<T>` that subscribes both ways to the changes of the based property `Synced.Value`, it does fire, but I'd like to get it done in an automated way -- if possible.

Comment: Same for me. I have used code like this: https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/when-any/#null-propogation-inside-whenanyvalue